# how to change compatibility mode in websphere 7

Tags: websphere-7

> how to change compatibility mode in websphere 7 like IIS server in windows.

how to change compatibility mode in websphere 7 like IIS server in windows.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Please provide more information about what you really asking...

Comment: For IE 10 browser compatibility mode change we did it in code and we need to change in the server level configuration. is there any option to change IE10 browser compatibilty mode config in websphere server 7? , Like IIS server in .Net application we can do this in the serverlevel config change.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'compatibility mode' in WebSphere Application Server, if you need it you will have to `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` to your pages and servlets.